# How can I pass API payload values to Ampscript in an inbox message?

Tags: mobilepush

Is there a way to trigger an app inbox message via API while passing through values that AMPScript can use for personalisation? We've achieved this for push notifications using the transactional messaging API `/messaging/v1/push/messages/`, however, I have discovered this API can't be used for in-app messages.

I have also tried using the `/push/v1/messageContact/{messageId}/send` and while you can trigger in-app messages, I don't believe you can retrieve values from the customKeys or customPayload objects with ampscript.

Is the only way to enter the contact into a journey with an in app message using `/interaction/v1/events`? Ideally I'd like to fire the message directly, rather than trigger a journey containing a message so that the contact receives the message as fast as possible.